# How can I set up a VisualStudio-like development loop using VsCode and windbg?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windbg

I would like a way to use WinDbg as a daily debugger for c++ app development. For that to be a viable scenario, it would require the ability to set windbg breakpoints from within VsCode, and then press F5 to run the program.
Is there any way that such a development loop could be set up for windbg?

Comment: write an extension to interface through the Debugger Protocol to WinDbg, but it much easier to use gdb or VS debugger in VSC because they already work (I don't know of the debugger clang uses)

Comment: Iirc there are already two such extensions though i havent tried them i use cdb in terminal and shell args in settings.json to build and debug  goto extensions button in sidebar and type windbg-debug and or cdb-debugger to install the extensions